# Regex in Java get part of string

Tags: java, regex

I'm having trouble with regex in Java. I'm trying to capture the central part of a string between two parts:

```
function gH(a){a=a.split("");
```

and

```
return a.join("")};
```

The problem is that the center of the string changes all the time. And the name of function, too.

Here is an example:

```
;function gH(a){a=a.split("");fH.vF(a,36);fH.DZ(a,42);fH.kG(a,1);fH.vF(a,23);fH.DZ(a,29);fH.vF(a,41);fH.DZ(a,2);fH.kG(a,2);fH.vF(a,17);return a.join("")};
```

The part I want is:

```
fH.vF(a,36);fH.DZ(a,42);fH.kG(a,1);fH.vF(a,23);fH.DZ(a,29);fH.vF(a,41);fH.DZ(a,2);fH.kG(a,2);fH.vF(a,17);
```

Here is my code:

```
pattern = ";function ..\\(a\\){a=a\\.split\\(\"\"\\);(.*?);return a\\.join\\(\"\"\\)};";//;return a\\.join\\(\"\"\\)\\};";

r = Pattern.compile(pattern);

m = r.matcher(response);

String code = "";

while(m.find())
{
    shift = m.group(1);
}

System.out.println("Center:" + code);
```

This code doesn't return what I want.

Comment: What is the output? I don't have a java compiler on me.

Comment: Also the code you posted won't do anything, the variable **code** isn't changed or assigned at any point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you are, fixed a couple of issues, and now it is working (see [sample program here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_java_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMZFpNWmNZN0ZCaGs)):

```
String response = ";function gH(a){a=a.split(\"\");fH.vF(a,36);fH.DZ(a,42);fH.kG(a,1);fH.vF(a,23);fH.DZ(a,29);fH.vF(a,41);fH.DZ(a,2);fH.kG(a,2);fH.vF(a,17);return a.join(\"\")};";
String pattern = "function\\s+..\\(a\\)\\{a=a\\.split\\(\"\"\\);(.*?)return\\s+a\\.join\\(\"\"\\)};";
Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher m = r.matcher(response);
String code = "";
while(m.find())
{
   code = m.group(1);
}
System.out.println("Center:" + code);
```

Output:

```
Center:fH.vF(a,36);fH.DZ(a,42);fH.kG(a,1);fH.vF(a,23);fH.DZ(a,29);fH.vF(a,41);fH.DZ(a,2);fH.kG(a,2);fH.vF(a,17);
```

`code` is now correcly assigned the value of the first capturing group, and used later. I also prefer `\s` over literal spaces as it is more convenient to debug regexes later.